# Enumeration of input types css shortcut

Tags: css

Can I write this shorter in CSS? 

 `#reg-form input[type="text"],#reg-form input[type="password"] {
     width: 200px;
     padding: 0px;
 }`

Something like (enumeration of values): `input[type="text or password or etc.."]`

**Edit:**

```
To prevent questions starting Why, what, etc. I'm programmer so I'm lazy so I wanna improve my CSS skills to write it shorter and more synoptic.
```

Comment: I think this is as far as you will get, but please do explain why you need it to be shorter?

Comment: A different solution but you could just add a new class to all the text and password inputs in the form.

Comment: @Ibu I don't need, I want :)

Comment: @acfrancis Actually it makes it longer, cause you need to write class to each element you wanna style..

Comment: I was thinking of a solution like the one in @LeonardoR's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestions is that you use a `class` to select your elements. For example:

```
.input-class {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Then:

```
<input type="text" class="input-class" />
<input type="password" class="input-class" />
```

But the straight answer to you question is **no**. You could do some hacky thing like:

```
input:not([type='checkbox']) {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

That would apply this to all input elements except for the checkbox ones. But it's not a beautiful thing. So:

```
input[type='text'], input[type='password'] {}
```

is the smallest thing that you can do.

Comment: + for the rest after class advise, cause class makes it even longer :D 
I give it two days if somebody not come with solution then I mark your answer that its not exist a shortcut ;)

Comment: Vote up for the interesting question as well.

Comment: How is `input:not([type='checkbox'])` hacky...?

Comment: @JoshC because the styles would be applied to other `inputs` as well. Not just `text` and `password`.

Comment: @LeonardoR. I dissagre with your latest comment. Cause this selective style has some reason, especially for setting width. When you make a form you usually wanna have same width input text fileds, password fields (which is basicaly also just textfield with some add) and maybe some other, BUT if you set theese to widht 200px, you dont usually want have 200px with for submit button which is input type="submit" ...

Comment: @JoshC check this JSFiddle. It shows what I'm trying to say. ALL other inputs that aren't a checkbox, are going to have 200px. http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/Rq8uc/